# Reading data from Firebase and save it in Array list

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to retrieve data from the database and save it into an array list I get the following error: `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap`

```
@Override
    public List<Player> getPlayers(String gameId) {
        final List<Player> commentKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference nishi = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("players");
        Query query = nishi.orderByChild("game_id").equalTo(gameId);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    commentKeys.add((Player) childSnapshot.getValue());
                }
                Log.d("Data:", commentKeys.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return commentKeys;
    }
```

This is my `Player` class:

```
public class Player {

    private String playerId;
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private int points;
    private String gameId;

    public Player() {
    }

    public Player(String id, String name, String color, int points, String gameId) {
        this.playerId = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.points = points;
        this.gameId = gameId;
    }

    public String getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(String playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getGameId() {
        return gameId;
    }

    public void setGameId(String gameId) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `childSnapshot.getValue()` does not return an object of `Player` class even if you are casting it to `Player`. Because a Firebase database is structured as pairs of key and values, which means that every node of your Firebase database is a `Map`, on that particular location you are not getting an object of `Player` class, you are getting a `java.util.HashMap`. It seems like you're simply reading the data at the wrong level in your JSON tree. The solution is to attach your listener on the correct level in the tree, which should be mapped exactly like your `Player` class.

And don't forget to add the declation of your `List<Player> commentKeys = new ArrayList<>();` inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will always be null.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: I will try it out know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clarify what kind of data gets your childSnapshot.getValue:

```
 for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
     commentKeys.add((Player) childSnapshot.getValue());
 }
```

If it gets HashMap so you should change your:

```
final List<Player> commentKeys = new ArrayList<>();
```

I hope it will help.